# Get Xml content into a string from a subchild using c#

Tags: c#, xml, linq, xelement

It is my first time posting, and I am very new to C#, so I appreciate the help. I have so many variations of this code that are close to what I need, but I can't get on my own.

I am trying to get the contents of a sub-child in an XML sting using c#. This is the sting I receive:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<activation>
    <activationOutput>
        <AID>7706a84f-5sef5-4b49-891c-98414ebb61d5</AID>
        <protectionKeyId>18305465463798407</protectionKeyId>
        <activationString>encoded xml string</activationString>// What I need
    </activationOutput>
    <activationInput>
        <activationAttribute>
              <attributeName></attributeName>
              <attributeValue></attributeValue>
              <isvPermission></isvPermission>
              <endUserPermission></endUserPermission>
        </activationAttribute>
        <activationAttribute>
           <attributeName></attributeName>
                <attributeValue></attributeValue>
        </activationAttribute>
        <comments></comments>
    </activationInput>
</activation>
```

I need to get the **activationString** value out into a string. Having the other elements would be nice, but I only care about getting  into a string v2c called. The information in between the  tags is another encoded XML string.

I first bring the sting into an XML element using:

```
XElement rootActivation = XElement.Parse(encodedActivationResponse, LoadOptions.SetLineInfo);
```

What has got me stumped is how to get the sub child  out as a string. Using XElement element gets me the values for all of the children under ActivationOutput, but I only need the last one.

```
string activationOutput = rootActivation.Element("activationOutput").Value;
```

It sends me a long unusable string

```
7706a84f-5sef5-4b49-891c-98414ebb61d518305465463798407encodedxmlstring
```

I've also tried:

```
IEnumerable<XElement> activationString = rootActivation.Elements("activationString");
```

It looked promising, but I don't know how to get the value out as a string. It shows as

{System.Xml.Linq.Extenstions.GetDescendantsXElement>}

I was hoping that I could take the variable and push it into a string using:

```
string v2c = activationString.ToString;
```

But that does not work either

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt

```
string activationOutput = rootActivation.Element("activationOutput").Value;
```

does give you a concatenation of all the `text()` nodes that are children of `<activationOutput>`. Obviously, that's not what you want.

To solely get the `<activationString>`'s `text()` node use

```
string activation = 
  (string)rootActivation.Element("activationOutput").Element("activationString").Value;
```

One restriction of this approach is: it only gets the first of each elements.

Comment: This is exactly what I have been looking for. Thank you so much. I knew it was some combination of all the elements that I tried.

Answer (score 0):

If that is the only element called activationString you could just do

```
string activationString = XDocument.Parse("xmlFilePathHere").Descendents("activationString").FirstOrDefault().Value;
```

Answer (score 0):

In VB.Net

```
    Dim rootActivation As XElement
    'for testing
    rootActivation = <activation>
                         <activationOutput>
                             <AID>7706a84f-5sef5-4b49-891c-98414ebb61d5</AID>
                             <protectionKeyId>18305465463798407</protectionKeyId>
                             <activationString>encoded xml string</activationString>
                         </activationOutput>
                         <activationInput>
                             <activationAttribute>
                                 <attributeName></attributeName>
                                 <attributeValue></attributeValue>
                                 <isvPermission></isvPermission>
                                 <endUserPermission></endUserPermission>
                             </activationAttribute>
                             <activationAttribute>
                                 <attributeName></attributeName>
                                 <attributeValue></attributeValue>
                             </activationAttribute>
                             <comments></comments>
                         </activationInput>
                     </activation>

    Dim activationString As String = rootActivation.<activationOutput>.<activationString>.Value
```